# $\sum_{n\geq1} k_n x_n$ converges for every $x \in l_1$, then $\sup_{n\geq1} |k_n| < \infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $(k_n)$ be a sequence of scalars. Prove that

$(a)$ if $\sum_{n\geq1} k_n x_n$ converges for every $x \in l_1$, then $\sup_{n\geq1} |k_n| < \infty$.

$(b)$ if $\sum_{n\geq1} k_n x_n$ converges for every $x \in c_0$ then $\sum_{n\geq1} |k_n| < \infty$.

For the second part I have used Uniform Boundedness Theorem. Require help in the first part.

Thank You.

Comment: Try to do a proof by contradiction. Suppose that $k_{n}$ is unbounded. Can you find an $\ell^{1}$ sequence which makes the "weighted sum" unbounded?

Comment: The uniform boundedness theorem also works for the first part. You are supposed to show that $(k_n) \in l_{\infty}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $ (k_n) \notin\ell_\infty$ then it has a subsequence $(k_{n_p})$ such that $\mid k_{n_p} \mid \geq p$. Define $x_{n_p} = \frac{1}{p k_{n_p}}$ and rest of the terms $0$. Easy to check that $x \in \ell_1$ and $\sum_{n\geq1} k_n x_n$ divergers. A contradiction.